# ion-view is not a known element

Tags: angular, ionic2

following is my content for ionic page:

```
    <ion-content padding class = ""view-content">
    <form>
        [form content here...]
    </form>
    </ion-content>
```

my css file:

```
.view-content {
    background: url("background.jpg");
```

but it is not working and i'm getting the following error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'ion-view' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-view' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-view' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
[ERROR ->]<ion-view view-title="My Page">
<ion-content>
 Hello!
")
```

can any tell me what am I doing wrong here or how to solve this.
I'm new to ionic framework, infact new to web development.

Comment: are you using ionic 1 or ionic 2?

Comment: Please share your component code.

Comment: ion-view is a component in ionic 1 and not in ionic 2.

Comment: i'm using ionic 2. is there any way by which i can use it in ionic 2. i want it to set background as image

Comment: yes..only background image for ion-content?

Comment: background as an image for complete page. How can i do that?

Comment: also make sure you give the path

Comment: tried that too. doesn't work either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ion-view is a valid component in ionic version 1 and not available in version 2.

In order to set image background you can set a css class and set 'background' attribute

```
<ion-content class="view-class">
 Hello!
</ion-content>
```

In your corresponding scss

```
.view-class {
   background: url("path_to_image")
}
```

**EDIT:** [sample plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7GFR6bjXE7yLe0PGQTiB?p=preview)

Comment: i'm able to set background color but not an image.

Comment: its working in the plunker.. give the relative path to your image.. it should work

Comment: my image is in the same folder as my other scss and html files. path is correct.

Comment: its for testing purpose only...so that i can get it to work....i don't think that path is an issue

Comment: on the contrary.. ionic will build it and move it accordingly to the www folder from assets.. it wont move images from src..

Answer (score 1):

i Dont know much about ionic but seems error is in module

```
<ion-view view-title="My Page">
    <ion-content>
      Hello!
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
```

according to error if you are using `ion-view` or any component in your app, than you must add that component in the main module.

like in angular2 we did the same in `app.module.ts` file where we tell the angular which components are we going to be load on the load of app.

like this

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    here component list, directives and pipes
  ],
  imports: [
    ion-view, etc.....
  ],
  providers: [CanActivateViaAuthGuard, GlobalService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: <ion-view> is a directive from the Ionic Framework, you're answer is wrong.

Comment: okay so you can put your directives in the decalration part. is it right ?

Answer (score 0):

ion-view is not an element like it says. Remove 
and the closing

Comment: so any idea about how to add a background as an image for a page in ionic 2?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, I think the page or component you have created is in a separate module. Please add the IonicModule import to that module and import that module in app module.

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { ItemsComponent } from "./items/items";
import { ItemComponent } from "./item/item";
import { IonicModule } from "ionic-angular";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ItemsComponent, ItemComponent],
  imports: [IonicModule],
  exports: [ItemsComponent, ItemComponent]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```